# editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor'

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

in order to use monaco in below source code  I did install below package but I'm getting that type error. Why is that and how can I fix that?

package:

```
npm i monaco-editor
```

I'm using this command:

```
yarn install
```

the package file looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.13.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@codingame/monaco-jsonrpc": "^0.3.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.27.0",
    "monaco-editor-core": "^0.22.3",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.2",
    "monaco-languageclient": "^0.13.0",
    "normalize-url": "^2.0.1",
    "reconnecting-websocket": "^3.2.2",
    "request-light": "^0.2.2",
    "vscode-json-languageservice": "^4.0.2",
    "vscode-languageserver": "7.0.0",
    "vscode-uri": "^3.0.2",
    "vscode-ws-jsonrpc": "^0.2.0",
    "ws": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "yarn run clean && yarn run build",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "copy": "cp src/index.html lib/index.html",
    "build": "yarn run compile && webpack && yarn run copy",
    "start": "node lib/server.js",
    "start:ext": "node lib/server.js --external"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

And this the error I'm getting:

> src/client.ts:32:24 - error TS2345: Argument of type
> 'import("path/to/project/monaco-languageclient/example/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api").editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor'
> is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor'.

this is the full source code:

```
import { listen, MessageConnection } from 'vscode-ws-jsonrpc';
import {
    MonacoLanguageClient, CloseAction, ErrorAction,
    MonacoServices, createConnection
} from 'monaco-languageclient';
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
import normalizeUrl = require('normalize-url');
const ReconnectingWebSocket = require('reconnecting-websocket');

// register Monaco languages
monaco.languages.register({
    id: 'typescript',
    extensions: ['.ts'],
    aliases: ['TypeScript','ts','TS','Typescript','typescript']
})

// create Monaco editor
const value = `{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/coffeelint",
    "line_endings": "unix"
}`;
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container")!, {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(value, 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse('file:///abs/path/to/demo/ts/file.ts')),
    glyphMargin: true,
    theme: "vs-dark",
    lightbulb: {
        enabled: true
    }
});

// install Monaco language client services
MonacoServices.install(editor,{rootUri: "file:///abs/path/to/demo/ts"});

// create the web socket
const url = createUrl('ws://localhost:3000/ts')
const webSocket = createWebSocket(url);
// listen when the web socket is opened
listen({
    webSocket,
    onConnection: connection => {
        // create and start the language client
        const languageClient = createLanguageClient(connection);
        const disposable = languageClient.start();
        connection.onClose(() => disposable.dispose());
    }
});

function createLanguageClient(connection: MessageConnection): MonacoLanguageClient {
    return new MonacoLanguageClient({
        name: "Sample Language Client",
        clientOptions: {
            // use a language id as a document selector
            documentSelector: ['typescript'],
            // disable the default error handler
            errorHandler: {
                error: () => ErrorAction.Continue,
                closed: () => CloseAction.DoNotRestart
            }
        },
        // create a language client connection from the JSON RPC connection on demand
        connectionProvider: {
            get: (errorHandler, closeHandler) => {
                return Promise.resolve(createConnection(connection, errorHandler, closeHandler))
            }
        }
    });
}

function createUrl(path: string): string {
    return normalizeUrl(path);
}

function createWebSocket(url: string): WebSocket {
    const socketOptions = {
        maxReconnectionDelay: 10000,
        minReconnectionDelay: 1000,
        reconnectionDelayGrowFactor: 1.3,
        connectionTimeout: 10000,
        maxRetries: Infinity,
        debug: false
    };
    return new ReconnectingWebSocket(url, [], socketOptions);
}
```

Comment: Strange. I'm attempting to reproduce your error and it's working perfectly fine for me. Even when I explicitly type `editor` as `import("monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api").editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor`, there are no errors thrown. Is there any chance you could reproduce this in a CodeSandbox or similar?

Comment: @futur that's really strange but I hope it helps me, can I see what's your project like? I do accept even pastebin links.   did you use this import `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'`? which version of `monaco-editor` and `monaco-languageclient` are you using? I don't yet how put this specific project to work on codeSandbox but once I do, I'll let you know

Comment: Here's my as-minimal-as-possible reproduction: https://hastebin.com/evobaruvos.js -- I'm using `monaco-editor@0.27.0` and `monaco-languageclient@0.13.0`, per your `package.json`. It would also help if you could set up a minimal example in CodeSandbox like mine; no need for all your code.

Comment: I put it together in [a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shtern-gy4d8?file=/src/index.ts) for convenience, and there's still no errors being thrown. Can you edit your answer to include your tsconfig.json and TypeScript version?

Comment: @futur I just created a react app from scratch using `npx` and using monaco package within this worked really fine, to my surprise. However, if you close the repo and go to example folder and try to use the monaco editor and mono languageclient from there, you get the type error like in this thread. Can you compile this with monaco-editor (not monaco editor core) in your machine? what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, which example folder/repo are you referring to?

Comment: @futur this one https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/tree/master/example sorry I forgot the link

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error given the example project. However, let's move this to [a discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236270/discussion-between-futur-and-jack) so it's easier to communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be a conflict between the `monaco` namespace provided by `monaco-editor` and the namespace of the same name provided by `monaco-editor-core`. When both are installed as dependencies, TypeScript seems to assume that `monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor` is referring to the latter, which causes issues since the created `monaco.editor` is imported from the former.

To resolve this, removing `monaco-editor-core` as a dependency fixes the confusion and uses the correct typings for `monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor`.

Comment: I am getting below error if I remove `monaco-editor-core` and add `monaco-editor` as dependecny.

browser-example: src/client.ts(5,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor-core' or its corresponding type declarations.
browser-example: src/client.ts(61,28): error TS7006: Parameter 'model' implicitly has an 'any' type.
browser-example: src/client.ts(61,35): error TS7006: Parameter 'position' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 
and a lot more similar to this, I have chnaged 
`import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor-core'`
to `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';` in `client.ts`